# Google translate via HTML text link?

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

Is it possible to get Google translate to translate text after a user clicks on a link?

I've just gotten the Google translate tool but instead of the drop-down list (which messes up by sleek design), I would like to have a custom 'translate this' button or link. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I've decided to translate my content using Google translate direct input, then create mywebsite.com/french and load the french site there. Answers would be greatly appreciated though! I'm always open to learning. Thank you.

Comment: Don't do that. It will just make you look bad. If you are going to provide a translated version, then get a professional translator to do it. Otherwise people can use Google Translate themselves if they want the content in a different language.

Comment: What about these other online translation services?

Comment: Machine translation is poor, plain and simple. It is good for a user to get a rough idea of what a text says, but is awful for trying to publish something in a language you don't speak. If you want to publish in French, then get a fluent (and preferably native) French speaker to translate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because Google's Translate this page links to an external script on their server. Machine translation is not a substitute for manual or human translation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for make a link for translation :

```
<a href="#" class="adressstyle" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/translate?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&amp;langpair=en%7Cfr&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8'); return false;" title="Google-Translate-English to French ">French</a>
```

Example Website where I applied this : http://www.mandirpalace.com